# How to call method from when a button in a gridview is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a button within a gridview and when I click the button I need to get the text value of that button (which is different for each row).

Is there a gridview event that I can use so I can get the row of the button that was clicked in the code behind?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gvResults_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Type">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>' CommandName="Delete" />
<%--                        <a href="javascript:sendval('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>');"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %></a>--%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event of the GridView control.

```
protected void gvResults_RowCommand(object sender, 
  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
      {
        // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
        // CommandArgument property.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
        // from the Rows collection.
        GridViewRow row = gvResults.Rows[index];

        // Add your code here
      }
}
```

You can set `CommandArgument` like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" 
    runat="server" 
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>' 
    CommandName="Delete"
    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  />
```

Bind Event like

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvResults" OnRowCommand="gvResults_RowCommand"
```

Comment: @connersz, its can contain any string set by the programmer.

Comment: I tried using that code and giving the button a command name of Delete to test but it is never hit in the code behind.

Comment: @connersz, make sure you register the OnRowCommand event with the GridView.

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid and the commandargument property you added doesnt work at all because it doesnt like cype or the gridviewrow.

Comment: @connersz, Use `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'` or `CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ` I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Code is below:

In .aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Type">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" Text='<%#Eval("TenLop") %>' OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

In code behide

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        TextBox1.Text = button.Text;
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: You can get the text value of button and not using any event of the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just getting the `Text` value of the clicked button, first add the click event handler so `Button1_Click` method will be executed when the button is clicked:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustType") %>' OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

then get the `Text` value in `Button1_Click` method like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the clicked button text value
    string buttonText = ((Button)sender).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, don't use DataBinder.Eval as such expressions are late-bound using reflection, and will negatively affect performance: -

http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/how-to-avoid-databindereval-in-aspnet.html

[ASP .NET - What's going on behind an Eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630584/asp-net-whats-going-on-behind-an-eval)